# gcloud compute execute command remotely

Tags: ssh, google-compute-engine, gcloud

Currently, if I want to execute something on a VM, I copy files over like this:

```
gcloud compute --project <project_id> copy-files --zone <zone_name> /home/roman/source/dir roman@<vm_name>:/some/path
```

Then I need to SSH into it manually like this:

```
gcloud compute --project <project_id> ssh --zone <zone_name> <vm_name>
```

And then go and run some command:

```
cd /some/path
python example.py
```

How do I combine step 2 and 3 together and execute a command remotely?

Note:  I want to use gcloud or the python api.  I don't want to use 3rd party packages like Fabric.

Comment: I don't think it's possible. You can maybe add some metadata to the project and get it to run automatically on instance restart.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Try:

```
$ gcloud compute ssh --zone ZONE INSTANCE -- 'cd /tmp && python some.py'
```

From `gcloud compute ssh --help`:

```
 [-- IMPLEMENTATION-ARGS ...]
    Flags and positionals passed to the underlying ssh implementation.

    The '--' argument must be specified between gcloud specific args on the
    left and IMPLEMENTATION-ARGS on the right. Example:

        $ gcloud compute ssh example-instance --zone us-central1-a -- -vvv \
            -L 80:%INSTANCE%:80
```

Comment: Can we have the output of the command on the terminal ?

Answer (score 53):

A gcloud update that landed a week ago blocked passing ssh commands after '--' and effectively forces use of `--command` option for this. In this case use:

`gcloud compute ssh --zone ZONE INSTANCE --command 'cd /tmp && python some.py'`.

Answer (score 3):

Did it with a bit of a tangent; using the normal ssh client instead of `gcloud compute`:

```
ssh -i ~/.ssh/google_compute_engine roman@<vm_IP> 'python /some/path/example.py'
```

The gcloud ssh key is located at `~/.ssh/google_compute_engine`, which it uses.  It also requires the external IP address of the instance instead of its name.

Comment: Yes, `gcloud compute ssh` is just a wrapper.

Comment: BTW, this is documented [here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/connect/standard-ssh#openssh-client).