# How to trigger a command in Google Compute Engine

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

**Introduction**

I would like to trigger a Compute Engine remotely using gcloud for a bussiness process, from the documentation I see that it can be done [with this command](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference), which is a wrapper of the next command that I would like to use instead of installing the gcloud SDK.

`ssh -i ~/.ssh/gcloud_ce <instance_name>@<vm_ext_ip> 'ls'` to execute the `ls` command from my PC, but I am only welcomed by `Permission denied (public key)`.

**What I am missing to configure and achieve this goal?**

[Similar case, but the solution did not work for me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39098341/gcloud-compute-execute-command-remotely)

Answer (score 0):

Here's the following steps you can refer to for the `Permission denied (public key)`:

1. Generate ssh key using `ssh-keygen`
2. Copy the key.pub file contents
3. Append the contents to `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file `sudo nano ~/.ssh/authorized_keys`
4. Try to ssh the VM on your client.

you can also refer to this documentation on [Choosing an access method](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/access-overview) and [SSH Permission denied (publickey) on GCE](https://medium.com/htc-research-engineering-blog/ssh-permission-denied-publickey-on-gce-2f42ff73344d)

Comment: 1. Created a new public key on my Windows machine
2. Addded the public key to the VM instance to the authorized_keys
3. Tested the ssh command
4. Same error

Comment: have you tried to generate a `non-root` key maybe you are using a `root` SSH key, also edit your post and provide a screenshot of the error message.